# what does "6/6 CI" mean in music sheet for guitar?

Tags: theory, sheet-music, classical-guitar

I found this music sheet on the internet for my training to play classical guitar and now i'am confused what's "6/6 CI" mean in the music sheet? (Canon in D transposed to C for guitar)

[image: Music Sheet]

**UPDATE**
Thankyou for your answer @Aaron, and one more question about this, is it true "C" to be used is in this screenshot? but the orange line move to fret number 1 because "I" on the 6/6 CI indicates fret 1 and "C" on the 6/6 CI indicates chord C and 6/6 mean press all strings, so "6/6 CI" is like chord "F" ?[image: Picture from GuitarTuna]

Comment: To your question: Yes. The notes being played are F-F-A-C, which make an F major chord. However, the "C" in this case is not a chord symbol; it does not mean a C major chord. The "C" means to barre the strings. See the duplicate post for a complete explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The notation indicates a **barre**.

- "C" means that a barre is to be used ("B" is also sometimes used).
- "6/6" means to barre all six strings
- "I" means to barre at the first fret (it's a Roman number [i.e., capital] "I", rather than a lower-case "l".)